# fail2ban-regex doesn't match snort logfile in alert_json format

Tags: regex, snort, fail2ban

I try to match a fail2ban-regex with a snort3 logfile in alert_json format.

example alert_json output in log-file:
`{ "timestamp" : "21/03/22-12:23:56.370262", "seconds" : 1616412236, "action" : "allow", "class" : "none", "b64_data" : "lVAAFpTzAXEAAAAAoAJyELUuAAACBAW0BAIICikv9agAAAAAAQMDBw==", "dir" : "C2S", "dst_addr" : "6.7.8.9", "dst_ap" : "6.7.8.9:0", "eth_dst" : "00:11:22:33:44:55", "eth_len" : 102, "eth_src" : "11:11:22:33:44:55", "eth_type" : "0x800", "gid" : 1, "icmp_code" : 3, "icmp_id" : 0, "icmp_seq" : 0, "icmp_type" : 3, "iface" : "eth0", "ip_id" : 5814, "ip_len" : 68, "msg" : "ICMP Traffic Detected", "mpls" : 0, "pkt_gen" : "raw", "pkt_len" : 88, "pkt_num" : 2270045, "priority" : 0, "proto" : "ICMP", "rev" : 0, "rule" : "1:10000001:0", "service" : "unknown", "sid" : 10000001, "src_addr" : "1.2.3.4", "src_ap" : "1.2.3.4:0", "tos" : 192, "ttl" : 64, "vlan" : 0 }`

my fail2ban-regex which didn't match:

```
^\{.*\"src_addr\"\ :\ \"<HOST>\".*\}$
```

i tryed this on regexr.com and it match.
i already found out there is maybe some problem with the timestamp but i didn't figured out which?

can somebody help here?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

It'd probably depend on fail2ban version, for example latest fail2ban >= 0.10.6/0.11.2 does not require timestamp anymore (it would simulate "now"), so it shows to me the IP and current time (as I execute it):

```sh
$ fail2ban-regex -v /tmp/log '^\{.*\"src_addr\"\ :\ \"<HOST>\".*\}$'
...
Lines: 1 lines, 0 ignored, 1 matched, 0 missed
```

To specify own `datepattern` you have to set it in filter (or supply to fail2ban-regex with `-d` parameter), so this will work:

```sh
# either for timestamp tag:
$ fail2ban-regex -v -d ^\{\s*"timestamp"\s*:\s*"%y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S\.%f" /tmp/log \"src_addr\"\ :\ \"<HOST>\"

# or for posix seconds (probably better because don't need conversion):
$ fail2ban-regex -v -d '"seconds"\s*:\s*{EPOCH}\s*,\s*' /tmp/log '\"src_addr\"\ :\ \"<HOST>\"'
```

Note that in fail2ban configs you must escape every `%` as `%%` due to python ini-configs substitution rules. 
Also note that fail2ban cuts part of message matching date pattern out before it apply pref- or `failregex`.

Also note that your RE is a bit vulnerable, see https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/2932#issuecomment-777320874 for a better example.

Comment: "datepattern" was the hint i was missing at all. really thank you! got it working now. could you give me an example what exactly "vulnerable" means in this context? what is somebody able to do with weak failregex rules?

Comment: it means that because of the missing anchor (due to `.*` left and right), src_addr with IP can be found everywhere (e. g. in foreign input), so it is vulnerable against certain injections type on any foreign data stored in log, as well as has poor performance, so can cause slowing down of the filter on long messages (if intruders can flood with some parasitic messages without to cause a ban), etc.